# Open HTML email in default browser

Tags: html, email

I send out an HTML email newsletter from my home PC. Not from one of these campaign companies, so its not hosted or anything

What I'd like to do is put a clickable link at the top of the email newsletter, for example "if you'd prefer to read this email in your browser" and it would open the persons default browser.

I've seen where this done and the content is hosted online, but I would like the link to open in the persons default browser on their PC or whatever theyre using.

I havent managed to find any way to do this, is it possible and if so how ?
Many thanks if you can help

Comment: You can try using javascript `window.open()` method and then pass the html again to this method. However, some of the email providers doesn't allow to this it seems. I'm not sure whether it will work or not. However, I seen this before in bootply.com preview window.

Comment: @Ravimallya you can't use JS in html email.

Comment: oh. I never new it. Now I came to know after going through some SO threads. thanks for the head up, @John

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without hosting the email online somewhere. You don't have to use a email service provider, you can just upload it like a normal web page and link to it.